# What does ||| in unix bash script mean?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm reviewing some code previously written and I came across this section of code which I cannot understand.

```
pull_key ="^monthlyreport|||pull|||"
```

Does anyone have any clue what this command does?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the script? By itself, it does nothing. How is it later being used?

Comment: This is pretty embarrassing. I looked through the code again and it's just a string. I thought it was a special command but apparently it was a delimiter for one of the files the program was reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the literal line (with the space between `pull_key` and the `=`) then that's a call to a `pull_key` function or script. Assuming it isn't just an error that is.

If that space *isn't* there then that's an assignment and that is just a string on the right-hand side of the `=` (and any meaning to the contents are up to whatever ends up using that value).

Comment: Ah my bad, yes there isn't a space. I didn't know a space makes so much of a difference in unix.

Comment: The shell is very sensitive to spaces in many places (and in others it completely ignores spaces). Learning the difference is important. Assignments and `[ ... ]` contexts are space sensitive. Command lines and other unquoted contexts generally are not (i.e. `echo foo      bar` and `echo foo bar` output the same thing).